# Exibindo data no idioma incorreto

Tags: php

Eu já tentei o seguinte código no `php` e não deu certo:

`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8', 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252');`

Meu servidor `apache` está em um `centos` e está rodando php 7.

Está exibindo uma data que vem do banco de dados em inglês: `01-SEP-2018` e o certo é '01-09-2018'

Eu já usei a função `DateTime` e resolve, porém quando vem `null`, exibe a data atual.

Por acaso devo atualizar os pacotes de idiomas do `centos`?

```
                               <?php

                             setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", 
                              "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
                             date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

                                    $datapagamento = $ct['DATA'];
                             ?>

                              <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $datapagamento; ?></td>
                                <td>
```

O `array` `$ct` é preenchido com um retorno de um sql do banco de dados.

Comment: Mostre o código PHP, talvez seja possivel resolver nele diretamente sem ter que ficar dependendo de configurações relacionadas ao "sistema operacional"

Comment: Você pode fazer a formatação na própria consulta, dando o comando `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(suaData, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM suaTabela`

Comment: @adventistaam isso não deu certo, essa função não existe

Comment: `date()` ou classe `DateTime` não são afetadas pelo locale.

Comment: Existe sim no mysql. Olha [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) e [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). A menos que seu campo não seja do tipo date

Comment: não estou usando mysql

Comment: Então você deveria ter definido a tag na sua pergunta